# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined" While Using formArray in Recative forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am Creating Dynamic Form, using formArray. But I am getting encountered with
the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined"

```
enter code here
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 title = 'Trainner Registration Form ';
 registrationForm: FormGroup;

 get LanguagesForm() {
    return this.registrationForm.get('Languages') as FormArray;
 }

 addLanguage() {
  this.LanguagesForm.push(this.fb.control(''));
}


 constructor(private  fb : FormBuilder ) {}
   ngOnInit(){
     this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      personalDetails : this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.group({
        firstName: [''],
        lastName: ['']
      }),
      aboutYours: [''],
      dob: [''],
      // lang: [''],
      Languages: this.fb.array([]),
      wTT: ['']
    })
  });

}


onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.registrationForm.value);
  // this._registerationservice.register(this.registrationForm.value).subscribe(
  //   response => console.log('Success', response),
  //   error => console.log('Error',error)
  // );
}
```

}

Expected Result: If user Click on the button "Add Language", A new Input Field should be created.

Actual Result: I am Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined"

app.component.html File

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<h1>Welcome to {{ title }}!</h1>
</div>
```

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper >

  <mat-step  [stepControl]="personalDetails">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter Personal Details</ng-template>
    <div formGroupName="personalDetails">
      <div formGroupName="name">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name : </label>
            <input type="text"  formControlName="firstName" class="form-control"  >
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name : </label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control">
          </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>DOB : </label>
          <input type="date" formControlName="dob" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>About Yourself : </label>
          <textarea formControlName="aboutYours" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Language(s) : </label>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2" (click)="addLanguage()">Add Language</button>
            <!-- <input type="text" formControlName="lang" class="form-control"> -->

            <div formArrayName="Languages">
                <div *ngFor="let lang of langsform.controls; let i =index;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>


</mat-horizontal-stepper>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide addLanguage() function so we can see what is inside? @GRV

Comment: check mu answer you need to set the upper  parent from the form array 

Comment: use a getter and get the controls in your ts file. Your IDE will help you and you'll know your code is typescript safe

Comment: @HarisHajdarevic Please Check the updated code. Thank You

Comment: @GRV have you check my answer  ??

Comment: @malbarmawi yeah I have checked but I want to add the Textbox when the Click event occurs, For Instance, when the user clicks on the button, then a new text should be generated.

Comment: @malbarmawi your answer is absolutely correct but is text box is added manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you initialize the registrationForm object inside onInit and at this time the template has already been parsed so you should just add an `*ngIf="this.registrationForm"` on this div `<div formArrayName="Languages">`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but still getting the same type error.

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57953622/11004264

Answer (score 2):

this happen because you don't set the upper formGroup the the `personalDetails` so the rey to look fro control with name `Languages` in the `registrationForm` controls where the `Languages` is a controls in `personalDetails` form group,another thing you have a typo related to `LanguagesForm.controls` must be 'Languages.controls'

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Language(s) : </label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2" (click)="addLanguage()">Add Language</button>

  <div [formGroup]="registrationForm"> <!--  -->
    <div [formGroupName]="'personalDetails'"> <!--  -->

      <div formArrayName="Languages">
        <div *ngFor="let lag of registrationForm.get('personalDetails').get('Languages').controls; let i =index;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can use get property to get access to Languages Form like this

```
  langsform() :FormArray { 
    return this.registrationForm.get('personalDetails').get('Languages') as FormArray 
  }
```

*template*

```html
<div [formGroup]="registrationForm">
  <div [formGroupName]="'personalDetails'">

    <div formArrayName="Languages">
      <div *ngFor="let lang of langsform.controls; let i =index;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efs2im)

Comment: Thank You for your contribution. It really helped me alot.

Comment: Can you help me with this?https://stackoverflow.com/q/57953622/11004264

Answer (score 1):

You named your FormArray "Languages" and not LanguagesForm.

```
<div *ngFor="let Languages of registrationForm.controls.personalDetails.controls.Languages.controls; let i =index;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
</div>
```

Edit: 
I changed the getLangsform and the `<mat-step>` and `<form>` tags.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lc8mu1

Comment: what about the upper parent from the formArray 

Comment: Yeah i thought he posted only a code snippet and not the whole app.component.html. You are right :) he is missing formGroup and formGroupName

Comment: but also you answer is correct this was a typo and will cause an error  

Comment: @StefanoM. I Please Check The full code I have updated. Thank You.

Comment: @GRV Check my Edit :)

Comment: @StefanoM. Thank you so much ......! The answer is perfectly correct ...Its working

Comment: @StefanoM. Can You Help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57953622/11004264

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

In your HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <div formArrayName="languages">
        <label>Languages</label>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="languages">
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddLanguages()">Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let languages of registrationForm.get('languages').controls; let i = index">
          <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteLanguages(i)">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In your TS:

```
this.registrationForm = new FormGroup({
       'languages': new FormArray([])
});
onAddLanguages() {
const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
(<FormArray>this.registrationForm.get('languages')).push(control)
}
onDeleteLanguages(index) {
(<FormArray>this.registrationForm.get('languages')).removeAt(index)
}
```

Comment: have you check the others answer ??

Comment: Why you are asking this?

Comment: what the difference between your answer and others answers ?