# How to initialize object, array and object-array in angular service class?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How to initialize an object inside an object and array-object in angular service class?
I want to use the two-way binding into my-form, so I want to pass the variable from service class to Html template.

trainer.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Trainner } from '../trainner.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const headerOption = {
 headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

  export class TrainnerService {
     selectedTrainer: Trainner;
      _url = 'http://localhost:3000/trainner';

  constructor( private _http: HttpClient ) { }

  register(registrationFormData) {
    return this._http.post<any>(this._url, registrationFormData);
  }

  getAllTrainner(): Observable<Trainner[]> {
    return this._http.get<Trainner[]>(this._url, headerOption);
  }

  putTrainner(trainer : Trainner): Observable<Trainner[]> {
    return this._http.put<Trainner[]>(this._url + `/$(emp._id)`, trainer);
  }
}
```

I have model.ts file

```
export class Trainner {
personal_details: { type: Object,
    name: { type: Object,
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String
    },
    dob: String,
    about_yourself: String,
    languages_known: { type: Array<Object>,
        items: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    willingly_to_travel: String
};

}
```

Comment: `map` method could help you.

Comment: can you show me some syntax @ngShravil.py

Comment: Which variable exactly is the one you need to initialize?

Comment: As you can see i have a model.ts file, so I need to initialize that particular modal so that i can use two-way binding when an update event occurs @LahiruChandima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create multiple model classes. you can update the current model and create a `TrainerName.ts` class that holds the name object and `Language.ts` that holds the language object. like this:

```
export class TrainerName{
 first_name: String,
 last_name: String
}
```

and `Language` model class like :

```
export class Language {
items:  String       
}
```

and use it in your current model class like:

```
export class Trainner {
personal_details: { type: Object,
    name: TrainerName,
    dob: String,
    about_yourself: String,
    languages_known: Language[],
    willingly_to_travel: String
};

}
```

and in your service you can use `map`

```
getAllTrainner(): Observable<Trainner[]> {
    return this._http.get<Trainner[]>(this._url, headerOption).map(res => new Trainner(res));
  }
```

Comment: also you will need a constructor in your model class

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TcytFU8FQJlH37u0MxpjHFhtFRghjphB/view?usp=sharing    please check the picture, em still getting error @Jazib

Comment: @GRV yes you're getting an error because you're using `object literal`  and `TrainerName` is a type not a value. so you can use a constructor as

`name: new TrainerName(firstName, lastName) ` sth like this